# I am getting Assertion Failed error while running jmeter script But I have not used assertions in my script

Tags: jmeter, assertion

I am getting Assertion Failed error while running jmeter script But I have not used assertions in my script.

I was doing Load testing with 500 users and getting Assertion Failure errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably your script fails to download at least one so called "embedded resources" - image, script, style, font, etc. If you are not interested in the problems with the embedded resources - you can turn JMeter automatic check for [HTTP Status code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) < 400 by adding the next line to *user.properties* file:

```
httpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true
```

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

If you don't want the change to be permanent you can pass it on ad-hoc basis using `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -Jhttpsampler.ignore_failed_embedded_resources=true -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [JMeter Properties Reference: Miscellaneous configuration](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#miscellaneous)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try this for sure.